# Can I install a msys .bashrc file on a usb drive?

Tags: windows, git, bash, usb-drive, portable-applications

I'm using Git-bash (msys) as my command line tool. I would like to have basic commands like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/f/ppython275/App/Scripts
```

run automatically when I start my shell, but I would like it to be completely self contained, i.e. have the .bashrc file on my usb drive. Is this possible. If so where should I put the .bashrc file

Comment: This might be more appropriate on Super User or Server Fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.bashrc` must reside in `~` in order for it to be loaded automatically when you start Git-bash.

There are a couple of options:

1. Create a symbolic link (using `mklink` in Windows). This is only supported on NTFS filesystems and I believe it would work across filesystems.
2. Create a simple `.bashrc` file in your `~` that sources the file on the USB drive:

   ```
   source /path/to/USB/based/bashrc
   ```